# "join" a collection on itself in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, lookup, aggregation

Got following collection:

```
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2084, "DBFileID" : 105657, "Size_MB" : 1427 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2085, "DBFileID" : 105657, "Size_MB" : 1427 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2086, "DBFileID" : 105657, "Size_MB" : 1427 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2087, "DBFileID" : 105657, "Size_MB" : 1427 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105657, "Size_MB" : 1427 } );
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2084, "DBFileID" : 105658, "Size_MB" : 3873 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2085, "DBFileID" : 105658, "Size_MB" : 3878 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2086, "DBFileID" : 105658, "Size_MB" : 3881 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2087, "DBFileID" : 105658, "Size_MB" : 3882 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105658, "Size_MB" : 3883 } );
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2084, "DBFileID" : 105659, "Size_MB" : 3134 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2085, "DBFileID" : 105659, "Size_MB" : 3134 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2086, "DBFileID" : 105659, "Size_MB" : 3134 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2087, "DBFileID" : 105659, "Size_MB" : 3134 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105659, "Size_MB" : 3134 } );
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2084, "DBFileID" : 105660, "Size_MB" : 1149 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2085, "DBFileID" : 105660, "Size_MB" : 1149 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2086, "DBFileID" : 105660, "Size_MB" : 1149 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2087, "DBFileID" : 105660, "Size_MB" : 1149 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105660, "Size_MB" : 1049 } );
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2084, "DBFileID" : 105661, "Size_MB" : 107159 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2085, "DBFileID" : 105661, "Size_MB" : 107159 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2086, "DBFileID" : 105661, "Size_MB" : 107159 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2087, "DBFileID" : 105661, "Size_MB" : 107159 });
db.test.insert({ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105661, "Size_MB" : 107159 });
```

then retrieve highest DateID per DBFileID:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.test.aggregate([ { $group: {_id: "$DBFileID",lastDate: { $last: "$DateID" }}}])
{ "_id" : 105661, "lastDate" : 2088 }
{ "_id" : 105657, "lastDate" : 2088 }
{ "_id" : 105660, "lastDate" : 2088 }
{ "_id" : 105658, "lastDate" : 2088 }
{ "_id" : 105659, "lastDate" : 2088 }
```

and here is resultset I want in the end:

```
{ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105657, "Size_MB" : 1427 }
{ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105658, "Size_MB" : 3883 }
{ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105659, "Size_MB" : 3134 }
{ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105660, "Size_MB" : 1049 }
{ "DateID" : 2088, "DBFileID" : 105661, "Size_MB" : 107159 }
```

i.e. retrieve, for each and every DBFileID, its Size_MB for the highest DateID...

I tried to get this in a single aggregate + lookup query but to no avail...

Someone can help me ?

In advance, thanks !
Regards,
Seb

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort documents by `DateID` in descending order
2. Group documents by `DBFieldID` and select *first* document from each group (that will be a document with max `DateID` value
3. Project results to get fields you want

Query:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $sort: { DateID: -1 }},
  { $group: {_id: "$DBFileID", doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }}},
  { $project: { _id:0, DBFieldID: "$_id", DateID: "$doc.DateID", Size_MB: "$doc.Size_MB" }}
]);
```

Output:

```
{ "DBFieldID" : 105661, "DateID" : 2088, "Size_MB" : 107159 }
{ "DBFieldID" : 105660, "DateID" : 2088, "Size_MB" : 1049 }
{ "DBFieldID" : 105659, "DateID" : 2088, "Size_MB" : 3134 }
{ "DBFieldID" : 105658, "DateID" : 2088, "Size_MB" : 3883 } 
{ "DBFieldID" : 105657, "DateID" : 2088, "Size_MB" : 1427 }
```